# Cannot adding a table in Database via persistence.xml using Hibernate Jpa , Tomcat and Mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, persistence

I'm working in flex, blazeds,hibernate jpa, tomcat and mysql.
This is the problem that I face when I start the project:

```
05.06.2012 22:33:29.459  INFO     org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version     - Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
05.06.2012 22:33:29.479  INFO     org.hibernate.cfg.Environment             - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
05.06.2012 22:33:29.482  INFO     org.hibernate.cfg.Environment             - hibernate.properties not found
05.06.2012 22:33:29.487  INFO     org.hibernate.cfg.Environment             - Bytecode provider name : javassist
05.06.2012 22:33:29.493  INFO     org.hibernate.cfg.Environment             - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
05.06.2012 22:33:29.645  INFO     org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
05.06.2012 22:33:29.650  INFO     org.hibernate.ejb.Version                 - Hibernate EntityManager 3.4.0.GA
```

And this is my persistence.xml file under src/META-INF:

```
<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="consultant_db">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>


    <class>com.adobe.demo.domain.Permission</class>
    <class>com.adobe.demo.domain.Role</class>
    <class>com.adobe.demo.domain.User</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/consultant_db" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="6" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>


</persistence-unit>
```

But if I delete the line:  `<class>com.adobe.demo.domain.User</class>`
the other 2 tables will be created.
What should I do?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The log entries you pasted are just information entries. And how is the User entity mapped?

Comment: when the project get started with these 3 class , no entity will be added to the database , but when i delete the User class, they other 2 classes will be added .

Comment: I think there already exists `user` table in mysql for managing accounts.

Comment: hey Nayan , i dont think so , because i created already another database for testing, but always the same problem .

Comment: @NayanWadekar shouldn't matter since it is a different database, this should only give a warning since user is an sql reserved keyword. Also, OP, can you post your user class with annotations?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923904/one-table-is-not-being-created-by-toplink) is a similar question. The OP was trying to create a "User" table, which failed. The OP was able to resolve the issue by annotation his `User` class with `@Table(name = "\"user\"")`.

I also gave some tips on how to troubleshoot such problems.